# Using a "normal" constexpr function argument in a template

Tags: c++, templates, c++17, constexpr

Let's say I have this function:

```
constexpr void foo(size_t x)
{ }
```

And this template:

```
template<size_t X>
class bar;
```

Would it be possible to instantiate an instance of template bar with the constexpr size_t x inside the foo function if I know that I will always constexpr evaluate that function (C++17)?

Answer (score 1):

If I understand you correctly you want this:

```
constexpr void foo(size_t x)
{
    bar<x> b{};
}
```

This is not possible because a `constexpr` function can be evaluated at runtime, in which case the argument `x` is not a compile time constant.

What you need to do is make the argument a template argument instead:

```
template <size_t X>
constexpr void foo()
{
    bar<x> b{};
}

// call it like this:
auto test()
{
     foo<24>();
}
```

Comment: That is not possible unfortunately because im calling the foo function from another constexpr function, which has it as a normal parameter.

Comment: @AndreasLoanjoe and what is the problem that prevents you to call `foo` like this?

Comment: I got the value passed into a constexpr function by value not as template parameter before I want to call foo. Lets say the test function above is also a constexpr function and got size_t as argument how would you do it then.

Comment: @AndreasLoanjoe you cannot use a function parameter for the reasons I told. You need to apply the same treatment up the call stack, i.e. make the `x` template argument all the way.

Comment: :( Will this change with constexpr bang functions or consteval in 20?

Comment: @AndreasLoanjoe I think consteval and constexpr bang were competing and since consteval made it into the standard I suppose constexpr bang is abandoned. I don't know if it should work with consteval, but both gcc and clang reject the code atm even in consteval function